# Java: Where is Autowired.Value looking for a setting?

Tags: java, spring, visual-studio-code

I've inherited a large-ish Java project using org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired, among other things.

I have one module that starts like this:

```
@Autowired
public Application(
    FlattenByFeedRunInvoker flattenRunInvoker,
    @Value("${jobId:}") String jobId,
    @Value("${instanceId:}") String instanceId,
    @Value("${feed}") String feed,
```

When I run it under debug, using this config:

```
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-Application<tbsm-reporting-etl-flatten>",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "com.tbsm.reporting.etl.flatten.Application",
        "projectName": "tbsm-reporting-etl-flatten"
    }
```

I get the message:

> [ERROR] 2019-07-23 10:10:58.137 [THREAD ID=main]
>   [CLASS=(SpringApplication:771)] - Application startup failed
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'feed' in value "${feed}"

I'm guessing that the framework is trying to find a value labelled "feed" somewhere. FWIW I *do* have a file called "default.properties" in the "resources" directory for the project and that file has the line

```
feed=myfeed
```

It looks like that file or value is not being found.  I'm wondering if it is just in the wrong directory wrt the program i'm running:

```
..\src\main\java\com\tbsm\reporting\etl\flatten\Application.java
```

vs

```
..src\main\resources\default.properties
```

Or if I need to do something else to tell it where to look.  e.g. does the vscode launch config need something else?

Comment: it should be `application.properties` not `default.properties`

Comment: Or if you don't want to rename `default.properties` use `@PropertySource` to load it.

Comment: I tried it by copying default.properties to application.properties and it worked!  Thanks!!